# error 404 on hitting http://<host>:8080/cs/REST/

Tags: rest, webcenter, fatwire, webcenter-sites

I had successfully configured Oracle webcenter on some of my VM.

To access it from my local machine I did some changes in firewell setting.

Then after the home page is not accessible and i get `404 error`.
i.e.,

**http://:8080/cs/REST/**   is not accessible where as some other REST URLs are accessible such as :

> **http://:8080/cs/REST/types/**
>
> **http://:8080/cs/REST/sites/**
>
> **http://:8080/cs/REST/sites/FirstSiteII/**

I think something wrong with my asset type configuration. How to resolve? 
Any idea would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at log files which can be generated by the content server.
The “View Server Output” menu provides access to the most recent server output logs. 
Iirc, you can set different levels of tracing and you should select the option(s) which are relevant to you issue - otherwise the trace log file will generate a huge amount of text - much of it irrelevant to you & making it particularly hard to read.
The log file is timestamped but it would be better served if you have a single-user make a single attempt to land on your URL(s).

Server output also contains tracing output if enabled. Tracing is typically enabled while 
debugging errors. If server output is being captured in a file, the file could grow large if tracing options are enabled. Consider disabling all server tracing options (especially if “verbose” option is checked), to keep server output file size in check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there's anything served at /cs/REST/ - what would you expect to see?